# d3.js doesn't load in the Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js, asset-pipeline

I am trying to port some d3.js code I wrote into a ruby on rails 3.2 app. I seem to have everything ported except rails will not load d3.js, even though it loads all the rest of my javascript.

in development.rb I have:

```
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
```

I have tried including it both through application.js as well as adding it in my view using

```
  - content_for :javascript_include do
    = javascript_include_tag 'ems/reports/floor_logs/d3'
```

in both cases the script tag gets correctly included in my rendered source

```
   <script src="/assets/d3.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the rails server logs it rendered with 200 Ok.

however in the console it says GET failed. When I load the url for the js :3000/assets/d3.js in my browser, it loads the text of the file quickly but it continues to load indefinitely.

Also if I take the code from d3.js and post it into another one of my javascript files which loads normally otherwise, it causes that file to have the same problem.

Comment: I guess that there might be problems because d3.js contains UTF-8 symbols inside it's source code (pi constant, for example). But I have no much info about how to avoid this.

Few minutes ago I've downloaded d3.v3.zip, unpack it to vendor/assets and add it to my application.js by sprockets require statement. It goes fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.The minified version doesn't have the non UTF characters and that gives me the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am still not completely sure why I wasn't able to successfully serve d3js through the asset pipeline (maybe something to do with https) I was able to get my code working by using a hosted version of d3js.

```
= javascript_include_tag '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.8/d3.min.js'
```